# Spark phoenix read breaks due to hbase-spark dependency with ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am writing a simple spark program to read from Phoenix and Write to Hbase using Spark-Hbase-Connector. I am successful in reading from Phoenix and write to Hbase using SHC separately. But, when I put everything together(adding hbase-spark dependency in specific) the pipeline breaks at Phoenix read statement.

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableCatalog

object SparkHbasePheonix {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    def catalog =
      s"""{
         |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"employee"},
         |"rowkey":"key",
         |"columns":{
         |"key":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
         |"fName":{"cf":"person", "col":"firstName", "type":"string"},
         |"lName":{"cf":"person", "col":"lastName", "type":"string"},
         |"mName":{"cf":"person", "col":"middleName", "type":"string"},
         |"addressLine":{"cf":"address", "col":"addressLine", "type":"string"},
         |"city":{"cf":"address", "col":"city", "type":"string"},
         |"state":{"cf":"address", "col":"state", "type":"string"},
         |"zipCode":{"cf":"address", "col":"zipCode", "type":"string"}
         |}
         |}""".stripMargin

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("HbaseSparkWrite")
      .getOrCreate()

    val df = spark.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
      .option("table", "ph_employee")
      .option("zkUrl", "0.0.0.0:2181")
      .load()

    df.write.options(
      Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "4"))
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
      .save()
    }
}
```

pom:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <scala.tools.version>2.11</scala.tools.version>
        <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
        <spark.version>2.3.2.3.1.0.31-28</spark.version>
        <hbase.version>2.0.2.3.1.0.31-28</hbase.version>
        <phoenix.version>5.0.0.3.1.5.9-1</phoenix.version>
    </properties>

        <!-- Hbase dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hbase.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hbase.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-spark -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.3.1.0.6-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hortonworks</groupId>
            <artifactId>shc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Phoenix dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix-client</artifactId>
            <version>${phoenix.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix-spark</artifactId>
            <version>${phoenix.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HConnectionManager
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.HConnectionFactory$HConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(HConnectionFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:396)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.access$300(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2374)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2352)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2352)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:232)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:147)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:202)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:98)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getInputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:57)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getInputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:45)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.PhoenixConfigurationUtil.getSelectColumnMetadataList(PhoenixConfigurationUtil.java:279)
    at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRDD.toDataFrame(PhoenixRDD.scala:118)
    at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRelation.schema(PhoenixRelation.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:432)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at com.test.SparkPheonixToHbase$.main(SparkHbasePheonix.scala:33)
    at com.test.SparkPheonixToHbase.main(SparkHbasePheonix.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 24 more
20/05/19 16:57:44 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Phoenix read fails when I add hbase-spark dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.3.1.0.6-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I get rid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Just use either one of those connectors.

If you want to read phoenix table and the output table is not a Phoenix table, but standard HBase table, use just SHC or HBase Spark connector. They can read Phoenix table directly from HBase, without the Phoenix layer. See here the options: https://sparkbyexamples.com/hbase/spark-hbase-connectors-which-one-to-use/#spark-sql

If you want to save to Phoenix as well, just use the Phoenix conector for reading and writing.

Normally, mixing up connectors can cause conflict in building, since they may overlap in their internal classes, especially if you don't care to import exactly the versions that use the same HBase client under the hoods. Unless you have a really good reason to use different libraries for reading and writing, stick just with one of them that fits your needs the most.